# Does a random rearrangement of $[0,1]$ have non-zero mass?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

I'm not sure this question is well-defined, but also I feel like in some sense this makes sense and should have a formalization. Although I don't know where to begin.

If we randomly rearrange $[0,1]$, meaning each point is sent somewhere in $[0,1]$ independent of the other points, does the image of this have non-zero measure? I believe it should, because any such rearrangement should "equally distribute" $[0,1]$.

Edit: sorry by permutation I didn't mean a bijection.

Comment: What's the random distribution? What, precisely, do you mean by "permute" - do you mean choose a random bijection on $[0, 1]$?

Comment: If you _permute_ [0,1] you'll get [0,1] definitionally, which trivially has non-zero measure. I think you need to be more precise here.

Comment: To begin, you have to choose a subset $\Omega \subset [0,1]^{[0,1]}$ comprising the maps you want (bijections? Borel functions? continuous functions?), and define a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F} \subset 2^\Omega$ and a probability measure $P$ on $\mathcal{F}$.  Then you can let $A$ be the set of all $\phi \in \Omega$ for which $\phi([0,1])$ is Lebesgue measurable and has nonzero measure.  You may now ask whether we have $A \in \mathcal{F}$, and if so, what is $P(A)$.

Comment: Most of those steps have no obvious "natural" choice, and so indeed the question is not well-defined until you make those choices.

Comment: One kind of natural choice is to let $\Omega = [0,1]^{[0,1]}$ viewed as the uncountable product of $[0,1]$ with itself, let $\mathcal{F}$ be the product $\sigma$-algebra and $P$ the product of uniform measure.  That is as if you choose the outputs $\phi(t)$ to be iid U(0,1) as $t$ varies over $[0,1]$.  But $\mathcal{F}$ is annoyingly small, and IIRC the sets of injective/surjective/measurable functions are not in it.  So you can't even ask the question "what is the probability that $\phi$ is surjective".

Comment: (As a general principle, experiments with uncountably many independent random variables don't have nice mathematical properties.  Probability theory works a lot better on standard Borel spaces, which the above $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ isn't.

Comment: The 1974 book "Values of Non- Atomic Games" by Aumann and Shapley discusses why such a thing cannot be well-defined.

Comment: Sorry by permutation I didn't mean a bijection since that would be trivial.